# dynamically change routes in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a filter on my page like so.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "hot", root_path(:filter => ["hot"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "recent", root_path(:filter => ["recent"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "most popular", root_path(:filter => ["popular","day"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "most liked", root_path(:filter => ["liked","day"]) %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the almost exact same filter(aside from the path) on another page (for followed users):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "hot", followed_index_path(:filter => ["hot"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "recent", followed_index_path(:filter => ["recent"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "most popular", followed_index_path(:filter => ["popular","day"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "most liked", followed_index_path(:filter => ["liked","day"]) %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whats the best way to roll these into one partial? Right now I have a partial for each version which seems really messy to me.

EDIT:

I got this to work as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "hot", url_for(:action => "index", :filter => ["hot"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "recent", url_for(:action => "index", :filter => ["recent"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "most popular", url_for(:action => "index", :filter => ["popular","day"]) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "most liked", url_for(:action => "index", :filter => ["liked","day"]) %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've not tried this but can you pass the path into the partial as a variable using `locals`?

Comment: I can pass it the path, but then I'm not sure how to get the right params in each link

Answer (score -1):

You can try to implement helper method.